# Function to get the value from a key value pair by using the key when the key value pairs are stored in a single column

Tags: oracle, plsql, keyvaluepair

Imagine I had a table with the following structure in Oracle database.

```
ID  Name    Attributes
1   Rooney  <Foot=left>, <height=5>, <country=England>
2   Ronaldo <Foot=Right>, <height=6>, <country=Portugal>
```

I want to create a function in which can return the value of a specific attribute when I pass in the ID, Name and Key of the attribute I need. Is that possible.

The query inside the function I was trying to use to determine the foot of the player Rooney is something like this.

```
       SELECT Attributes
       AS tmpVar
       FROM Players 
       WHERE id = 1 AND Name = 'Rooney' and Attributes like '%Foot%';
```

Obviously it will give all the attributes but I just want his foot attribute. This is my first question here so please excuse If I made any novice mistakes and advice on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

`(.+?)` captures the `value`, using non-greedy match, retrieved as 1 (last argument)

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(Attributes,'<Foot=(.+?)>',1,1,NULL,1) as Foot 
FROM Players
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bda110/4)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Did not know the exact usage of REGEXP_SUBSTR in this kind of scenario. I read some documentation today.

Answer (score 0):

You could parametrize that, such as

```
SQL> with players (id, name, attributes) as
  2    (select 1, 'Rooney', '<Foot=left>, <height=5>, <country=England>' from dual union
  3     select 2, 'Ronaldo', '<Foot=Right>, <height=6>, <country=Portugal>' from dual
  4    )
  5  select name,
  6    replace(regexp_substr(attributes, '&&attribute=\w+'), '&&attribute=') result
  7  from players
  8  where id = 1;
Enter value for attribute: Foot

NAME       RESULT
---------- --------------------
Rooney     left

SQL> undefine attribute
SQL> /
Enter value for attribute: country

NAME       RESULT
---------- --------------------
Rooney     England

SQL>
```

Comment: Complicated than my scenario but usage of regexp_substr is what I needed to know.

Comment: Forgot to mention: you'd better re-design that data model and normalize it. Storing different information (foot, height, country) into the same column is usually a bad idea.